# Asp.Net Core 2 API - ViewModel is empty on post request (multipart/form-data)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core

I use React in front-end and I have a simple form with text inputs and one file input (I use a FormData object).

I use axios to send the request.

The request is sent correctly (already checked in Chrome Debug console).
Form sent :

```
> Accept:application/json, text/plain, */* Authorization:Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MjAzODMxMjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDAwMC8iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQwMDAvIn0.GfvFb4am3QxBdUgPIQX8OHLcg9G7vgovF4vwny-HiLg
> Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
> boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfuFU2JWOnbvNnK6L
> Origin:http://localhost:3000 Referer:http://localhost:3000/news
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186
> Safari/537.36
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryfuFU2JWOnbvNnK6L Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"
> 
> h
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryfuFU2JWOnbvNnK6L Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BackgroundImg"; filename="Package assignment3.png"
> Content-Type: image/png
> 
> 
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryfuFU2JWOnbvNnK6L Content-Disposition: form-data; name="users_id"
> 
> 5
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryfuFU2JWOnbvNnK6L Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content"
> 
> <p>jhl</p>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryfuFU2JWOnbvNnK6L--
```

On the server-side, I have this endpoint :

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [Route("{id}/news")]
        public IActionResult CreateNewsByUserId(int id, [FromForm]NewsViewModel newsViewModel)
        {    
            return Ok(newsViewModel);
        }
```

The ViewModel :

```
public class NewsViewModel
    {
        public string     Title;
        public string     Content;
        public IFormFile  BackgroundImg;
    }
```

And `newsViewModel` is empty.
However, I can get the form data either through `Request.Form` Object or if I rewrite the endpoint as this :

```
public IActionResult CreateNewsByUserId(int id, string Title, string Content, IFormFile BackgroundImg)
```

Why is newsViewModel empty ?

Thank you

Comment: try removing [FromForm], if it works

Comment: @AliShahzad I already tried, but it doesn't change nothing :/